# CORS XHR redirect not working

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am making a CORS request which returns a 202 empty response with a location header to query for data.

But the browser is not redirecting to the url in the location header. Tried it on Chrome/Firefox and it does the same.

```
 jQuery.ajax(url, options).done((result: any) => {                        
                    });
```

.done gets called immediately after 202 response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the HTTP specification, especially [this part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30):

> 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the
> recipient    to a location other than the Request-URI for completion
> of the    request or identification of a new resource. For 201
> (Created)    responses, the Location is that of the new resource which
> was created    by the request. **For 3xx responses**, the location SHOULD
> indicate the    server's preferred URI **for automatic redirection** to
> the resource. The    field value consists of a single absolute URI.

Since automatic redirection is only mentioned for 3xx responses (actually I've checked entire spec) then it means that for any other status code it depends on browser. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) also confirms that:

> To **provide information** about the location of a newly created resource.
> In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP
> status code of 201 or 202

I think it is safe to assume that that's just how browsers work. You will have to redirect manually.

Comment: That's good to know. Unfortunately the browser is not letting me read the headers. I have Access-Control-Expose-Headers:* set. I am very sure from the CORS spec whether wildcard is allowed or not here.

Comment: @user460025 I think that `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` should be a comma-separated list of headers and it does not allow `*`. Try it. If that doesn't help than I don't know how to help you, sorry.